# Скроллинг tbody?

Tags: html, css

Не могу нигде информацию найти, можно ли сделать скроллинг tbody?
Если обернуть всю таблицу в div, то скроллинг выходит некрасивый, названия столбцов исчезают при прокрутке, нужно чтобы скролился только tbody.

Использую таблицы [jtable](http://www.jtable.org/).

Если сделать как советуют везде(сделать display block), то ширина заголовков столбцов и самих столбцов будет не одинаковая.

```
thead, tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
overflow-y: auto; 
overflow-x: hidden;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без js походу не обойтись, может так?

```js
$('table thead tr th').each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).width($('table>tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').width() + 'px');
});
```

```css
tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
thead {
  display: block;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(2n){
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A architecto, blanditiis commodi corporis eius enim esse est explicabo fugiat fugit impedit magni, maxime mollitia nam natus, non quisquam repellat sint.
    </td>
    <td>Architecto doloribus ea eligendi ex itaque molestiae, odit quae qui rem tenetur. Ipsam itaque repellat sit voluptates. Amet dolorem impedit incidunt, odit optio perspiciatis vero voluptas voluptatibus. Enim, fuga, unde?
    </td>
    <td>Beatae esse facere in nam natus odio, perferendis quaerat quod rerum saepe sapiente sint soluta! Beatae culpa, cum doloribus enim esse excepturi in, iure minus molestiae odio recusandae reprehenderit vitae.
    </td>
    <td>Ab expedita fugit id illum laboriosam, libero, modi molestias numquam obcaecati odit ratione similique, sunt voluptates. Aperiam cum debitis doloribus eveniet mollitia. Eius inventore ipsum molestiae, natus officia repellat similique!
    </td>
    <td>Alias at atque consequatur delectus dolorem doloribus eos eum excepturi exercitationem fuga id illo ipsum, itaque labore, maxime modi obcaecati odio omnis placeat repellendus sit soluta vel velit voluptate voluptates!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad corporis iusto maxime modi molestiae nesciunt veniam voluptates voluptatibus voluptatum? Alias aperiam cumque cupiditate dolores fugiat minima perferendis repudiandae sunt.
    </td>
    <td>Adipisci aliquam architecto atque beatae consequuntur cupiditate deleniti dicta dignissimos distinctio eligendi esse exercitationem explicabo ipsam magnam magni nisi nulla obcaecati pariatur perspiciatis placeat provident quidem rerum saepe tempore,
      veniam!
    </td>
    <td>Alias, architecto doloribus, dolorum eaque earum et hic impedit maxime necessitatibus numquam officiis perspiciatis tempore vel! Dolor expedita ipsa labore nisi nobis odit omnis, perferendis quia quo temporibus ullam, vel?
    </td>
    <td>Ad aperiam asperiores blanditiis commodi cum cumque debitis deleniti dicta distinctio doloribus earum eligendi explicabo facere harum, incidunt maxime nam natus nostrum nulla porro quos ut velit vitae voluptates voluptatum!
    </td>
    <td>Ad corporis distinctio facilis magnam, pariatur porro ullam unde velit? Error, nemo vitae. Ab aperiam debitis dolores in iure nihil odio optio, quaerat quod voluptates. Corporis culpa deleniti porro reprehenderit!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci commodi consectetur consequuntur delectus enim, eos et ex excepturi illum incidunt iste molestias nesciunt perferendis, quasi, quisquam sed sit temporibus vitae!
    </td>
    <td>Alias autem illo incidunt ipsam magnam optio porro suscipit voluptas? Adipisci aliquid blanditiis consectetur consequatur consequuntur, deleniti ea illum laboriosam maxime modi necessitatibus nobis, omnis optio perspiciatis praesentium repellendus
      voluptatibus.
    </td>
    <td>Autem blanditiis consequatur dignissimos, dolores ducimus eum illo molestiae omnis quas repellat rerum ut veniam vitae? Consequatur doloribus facere incidunt laudantium libero magni sequi tempora voluptates! Aliquid enim perferendis quidem.
    </td>
    <td>Blanditiis cum dolore eius excepturi id quia sed totam. Ab aliquam amet architecto aspernatur consequatur dolore fugit labore minima molestiae pariatur quae qui quo, repudiandae similique sint, tempore unde voluptas?
    </td>
    <td>A ab accusantium ad aliquam aliquid animi aperiam assumenda aut beatae doloremque dolorum ea eligendi fugit id ipsa, itaque magnam magni mollitia nisi non officia porro quas quis quo sapiente!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquid aut autem consequuntur cupiditate delectus dicta dolor doloribus ducimus, est laboriosam maiores maxime minus necessitatibus placeat praesentium qui quidem, repudiandae?
    </td>
    <td>Animi dicta eos facere id illum in provident quibusdam rerum? Amet, beatae doloribus inventore magnam maiores maxime officiis sunt voluptas? Animi deserunt dolorem doloremque dolores eaque esse odit quod similique?
    </td>
    <td>Accusantium assumenda autem debitis dolor enim impedit in iusto nemo nesciunt numquam officiis pariatur quo sint, unde ut velit veritatis. Cum, dolorem eius in iure praesentium qui sint veniam voluptatibus!
    </td>
    <td>Eaque ex in ipsa quae quibusdam! Asperiores commodi id numquam possimus rem! Ad aliquam autem, blanditiis consequatur cum deserunt error excepturi ipsa labore modi nihil quis recusandae, repudiandae velit voluptate.
    </td>
    <td>Corporis eum facere inventore placeat repellat saepe, voluptatibus! Accusamus animi assumenda, culpa dignissimos eligendi error eveniet exercitationem impedit laboriosam maiores nam nesciunt possimus praesentium, quidem reiciendis sint tempore temporibus
      voluptatem.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad cupiditate deserunt nihil nostrum perspiciatis porro quos sequi temporibus? Debitis fuga inventore perspiciatis praesentium sunt. Accusamus aliquid animi aut distinctio quas.
    </td>
    <td>Accusamus accusantium consectetur debitis deleniti distinctio dolorem impedit inventore magni nihil nisi quam quibusdam sint, sunt voluptatem voluptates! Deleniti est facere inventore iusto nisi numquam quis reiciendis suscipit temporibus veniam!
    </td>
    <td>Architecto aspernatur assumenda beatae blanditiis consectetur deserunt dolor dolore, earum eligendi excepturi harum impedit iusto labore laboriosam magnam minima numquam quaerat qui quia quos repellendus sapiente suscipit veritatis voluptas, voluptatibus.
    </td>
    <td>Accusamus dignissimos doloremque ducimus facere magnam repellendus tempore. Ad aliquid beatae commodi, cupiditate dolor dolores est facilis magnam molestiae nisi nobis rem sint soluta. Accusamus alias amet doloremque iste molestiae?
    </td>
    <td>Asperiores deserunt harum in, molestias placeat porro rem voluptas! Ducimus explicabo fugiat ipsa non possimus vero voluptas! A ab, aliquam excepturi laborum, magni nobis pariatur quisquam quos, sed sit tempore!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A beatae cupiditate deleniti, doloribus explicabo iste, molestias nemo nostrum obcaecati, odit quasi quibusdam repudiandae sed tempora tempore temporibus totam veritatis voluptas!
    </td>
    <td>Accusantium ad, adipisci aspernatur autem, commodi debitis deleniti deserunt dolores error fuga fugit illo illum impedit ipsam magni maiores, mollitia obcaecati odit officia omnis quae quisquam quo repudiandae tenetur voluptatum!
    </td>
    <td>Dolorum ea eveniet excepturi fugiat fugit illum iste iure magni mollitia numquam officia porro praesentium quam quia quisquam rerum sequi similique sunt tenetur totam velit veniam vitae voluptas, voluptate voluptatum?
    </td>
    <td>Aliquam culpa delectus dicta distinctio eos esse excepturi fugit incidunt libero minima minus molestiae molestias nam natus nobis odio, officiis omnis quibusdam rem sequi sint soluta suscipit vel velit voluptatum?
    </td>
    <td>Accusamus asperiores blanditiis earum hic ipsa, iusto laudantium natus necessitatibus neque odit placeat porro quaerat quod quos sapiente sunt voluptatem! Beatae cum deleniti dolores, ipsum labore nam numquam sit veritatis!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque autem dolore molestiae obcaecati quis. Dignissimos distinctio ducimus ea excepturi fuga ipsum iste nesciunt non officia possimus quae quia, repellat repudiandae.
    </td>
    <td>A amet consequatur consequuntur corporis cumque cupiditate delectus distinctio dolores eos expedita fugiat in, incidunt iste iusto mollitia neque odio odit pariatur provident quos, ratione saepe sunt vel veniam vitae.
    </td>
    <td>A iure nobis rerum. Amet aut consectetur cumque, dolores ducimus esse expedita facilis illo necessitatibus nisi officiis, perferendis perspiciatis possimus velit, voluptas! Alias beatae deleniti deserunt eius laudantium quis tempora.
    </td>
    <td>Adipisci atque consectetur culpa dignissimos doloribus eaque eligendi explicabo impedit in magnam minima natus nihil nobis odio officiis perspiciatis placeat provident qui reiciendis sint tempora tempore temporibus, ullam vel vitae.
    </td>
    <td>Assumenda beatae, blanditiis consectetur cumque cupiditate ducimus hic id illum in laudantium minus mollitia natus, odit placeat possimus provident quasi quis quo recusandae repellendus sunt, velit veritatis. Ad, amet, iste.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aperiam corporis cum cumque, debitis delectus dolores doloribus ducimus, facilis ipsa ipsum minima nihil porro quod, tempora unde voluptate voluptatum! Obcaecati.
    </td>
    <td>Autem delectus harum modi qui reiciendis sapiente tempore temporibus! Ad amet corporis ducimus! Corporis dolores illum, impedit in libero magnam necessitatibus nisi nobis quae quaerat rem, repellendus rerum sequi ullam.
    </td>
    <td>Consequuntur dicta eaque iure libero maxime, tempora vero. Aliquid earum eum facilis harum itaque iure labore laborum laudantium mollitia nemo, neque non quaerat quisquam sapiente sequi, suscipit temporibus vel. Optio.
    </td>
    <td>Assumenda aut consequatur, corporis dolore ex, itaque iusto maiores maxime natus placeat quas quasi quis quos rerum sint totam unde veniam vero vitae voluptas? Maiores nesciunt obcaecati reiciendis rem suscipit!
    </td>
    <td>Aperiam cum deleniti, dicta est ipsum magnam maiores molestias nostrum optio porro qui quis quo repellat rerum similique soluta sunt voluptates. Culpa cupiditate delectus enim maxime officia possimus quibusdam ullam?
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab adipisci aut beatae commodi consectetur debitis deserunt dicta distinctio ea enim eos eveniet fugit natus necessitatibus obcaecati, porro quos sint tempore.
    </td>
    <td>Consequuntur dolores itaque laborum minus officiis saepe veritatis vitae. Deserunt explicabo impedit, iste labore maxime minima nesciunt, provident, quasi qui similique veniam vitae? Aliquam atque, dicta minima odio odit veritatis?
    </td>
    <td>Adipisci aliquam aperiam beatae deleniti dicta dolore earum est ex expedita fugit, incidunt inventore iure modi nemo non officia quibusdam quis ratione rerum similique tempora tempore totam voluptate! Beatae, iusto?
    </td>
    <td>Ad ex explicabo, minus officiis voluptatibus voluptatum. Cumque est illum neque optio quod totam voluptas voluptate. Aliquam earum eum impedit iste minima modi pariatur possimus totam vel voluptates? Nesciunt, quasi?
    </td>
    <td>Impedit itaque similique vero! Blanditiis enim fugiat reprehenderit ullam? Blanditiis distinctio nihil, numquam quia quod sunt! Architecto libero minus similique sunt veritatis. Est explicabo inventore laboriosam libero, mollitia perspiciatis soluta!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias aliquam assumenda dolorum, eius fuga id incidunt mollitia nulla perspiciatis praesentium quam saepe, sequi veniam! Autem labore neque quo sunt voluptatem!
    </td>
    <td>Ipsa ipsam praesentium saepe! Ad, atque enim error eveniet ex excepturi exercitationem, explicabo fuga illum laborum officiis optio quam quas quibusdam repellendus reprehenderit sed ut vitae? Corporis debitis quod vitae!
    </td>
    <td>Aspernatur blanditiis doloribus iste, laborum nemo voluptatum! Atque corporis deserunt dolore eius, eligendi eum ex inventore ipsum iste, iure libero minus officia perspiciatis repudiandae temporibus unde, vero! Distinctio, nemo velit.
    </td>
    <td>Animi aspernatur autem culpa debitis distinctio ducimus eos explicabo facilis fuga hic impedit in ipsum labore mollitia nam nobis non nostrum odit possimus provident quas quasi, ratione recusandae veniam vitae?
    </td>
    <td>Aut natus officia rerum. Animi debitis deserunt, dolorem enim eos excepturi explicabo hic, maxime nam perspiciatis quam quisquam, reprehenderit sint suscipit tempore tenetur vel voluptates! Aliquam cumque quas quod ratione.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```